# Reference for low-dimensional topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation, low-dimensional-topology

I have read topology and algebraic topology by Munkres and I want to start low-dimensional topology.
What is a good reference for starting low-dimensional topology?

Comment: It might be a good idea to read the first 3 chapters of Hatcher (or something equivalent). Munkres is really an undergraduate book and doesn't contain enough. Rolfsen's book is probably a good place to start after that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to read [Saveliev](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/128784) which has excellent topics and  graphics.

Comment: It might be an idea to specify that it's Nikolai Saveliev to whom you're referring, as there is also a Peter Saveliev who has written a book on topology.