# Notes on Low-Dimensional Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, 4-manifolds

I am studying algebraic topology at the moment and I'm halfway done with Hatcher's book. I am extremely interested in low-dimensional topology, so I was wondering if anybody knows a good set of notes in knot theory and 4-dimensional manifolds. So any reference would be much appreciated

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582500/reference-for-low-dimensional-topology

Comment: BTW what is the meaning of "half-way done"? I would suggest to focus on one topic first. For Knot theory- Rolefson, for 4-manifold Gompf and Stipschiz. Maybe you don't require much pre-knowledge for knot theory (in compare to 4-manifold). Also my personal suggestion would be to make the basics very strong before jumping into any big book.

Comment: I'd also recommend Lickorish "An Introduction to Knot Theory." For 3d topology: Hempel's and Schultens' books.

Comment: In addition to the above, I personally like Prasolov + Sossinsky's 'Knots, Links, Braids and 3-Manifolds'.

Answer (score 0):

There are many introductory books on knot theory. I will list few in an order of increasing difficulty.

- Adams: The knot book (2004), may be too easy since it doesn't even mention the fundamental group of a knot.
- Livingston: Knot Theory (1993)
- Murasugi: Knot theory and its applications (1996)
- Burde, Zieschang: Knots (2013)
- Kawauchi - A survey of Knot Theory (1996), not exactly a textbook but contains some proofs skipped by previous items.

I haven't read Lickorish's book, so can't judge it. Material listed above should more than enough to understand fundamentals of knot theory. If you want to continue your journey with knots you should switch to reading papers from journals.